# Is there any ways to set auto closing tag for XML in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml

```
  <TextView
   android:layout_width=""
   android:layout_height=""
```

> It seems like Android Studio has removed the auto closing tag?
> I have browsed and dont find any solution for this....

[Here is what its look likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqqmu.png)

Comment: I believe it has always been this way? I don't think this a recent change.

Comment: just press `/` at the end . i think this is how it was before too . you can check code style in Settings see if there is any other format which support this .

Comment: Can you tell me the specific setting u talking about? I cant find any clue bout this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First confirm that your project has finished background processes like indexing..

Then just typing **<** you will find suggestion...
After filling the recommended properties you need to type either

```
/
```

or

```
>
```

autocompletion will happen...
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these issue occurs with the idea.
Just go to File -> Invalidate and Restart
->Press blue button: Invalidate and Restart.